# python convert human to timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

My date is in following format:

> 19/Jun/2014:00:03:09

How to I convert it to epoch timestamp in python?

Note: I searched on date format in python, but could not find any format that matches above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) and then [`mktime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime).

```
import time

tt = time.strptime("19/Jun/2014:00:03:09","%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
print time.mktime(tt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

[reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

Answer (score 0):

use dateutil it will parse just about anything

```
$ easy_install python-dateutil

>>> import dateutil.parser as parser
>>> some_date_string = "19/Jun/2014:00:03:09"
>>> parser.parse(some_date_string)
```

[edit] oops nevermind ... apparently it cant parse this ...